# What NuGet is required for this namespace?

Tags: c#, nuget, claims-based-identity

I could make this question more specific, but, I keep encountering this from time to time and have finally given up and created this on S.O.

For this particular situation, I am following this Microsoft guidance on [how to call a downstream API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/) from my current API

In the aforementioned article, I dutifully downloaded the source code from Microsoft's github account.. and copied the required source code snippet into my project..

Everything is about ready to compile, except my Visual Studio IDE puts little squigglies under [this one piece of code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L139) (only the last segment)..

`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext`

I've already wasted a half hour or more trying to compare the masssive Nuget `packages.conf` file with my own.. and don't really want to port more than necessary into my own project..

Is there some magic way to discern *WHICH* nuget I need? I know how to right-click and `Go to definition` but.. sometimes the classname and/or namespace is not an immediate dead giveaway

---

UPDATE AFTER ALL YOUR NICE COMMENTS

---

Shall I even admit I've been doing .NET development for almost 12 years? No, I'd better not...

I'll say in my defense, that I did put this already in my usings..
[image: System.IdentityModel]

And it stayed greyed out which made me think:

- I must've already referenced this, else it'd have red squiggles
- But, it's not bold white, which means it's unnecessary

It did not occur to me:

- "because I have `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` nuget, it's now a legitimate namespace, but I don't have the central DLL still"
- nor did it occur to me that in this fairly-new-to-me world of OAuth token security, that any of this identity stuff would be in my installed framework when everything else including the kitchen sink has been a nuget

So, hopefully you guys with Coca-Cola spewing through your nose (I can hear your loud guffaws in the kitchentte down the hall) - can stop laughing long enough to cut a brother some slack

Comment: Please don't down vote without commenting

Comment: Have you tried googling for "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext" or "System.IdentityModel.Tokens"? Any search results in relation to nuget?

Comment: It looks like in this case you may be barking up the wrong tree with NuGet...That class can be found in `System.IdentityModel.dll`

Comment: Kinda scary when programmers get so caught up trying to glue other people's code together that they can't see the forest for the trees.  Big picture: the words "System" and "Microsoft" in a namespace are reserved to only one entity.  Google indexes their documentation.

Comment: Please learn how to use API Browser, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.bootstrapcontext?view=netframework-4.7.1#Applies_to as it is crystal clear that you need to add a reference which is already part of .NET Framework.

Comment: @LexLi  - I did use the API browser.. I just thought it was lacking this detail.. I read it with a jaded perspective that *I know I need a nuget - all token OAuth business is NuGet!!* and thus: *why isn't the API browser explaining it (my false assumption) to me?*

Comment: @LexLi - I also assumed the API browser was telling me it was simply compatible with .NET Framework 4.xxxx  - not that it was *part* of it

Comment: I can only comment that you misunderstood lots of concepts. 1) Do download the whole project from GitHub, as Microsoft makes it crystal clear where `System.IdentityModel` reference comes from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/TodoListService.csproj#L94 2) If .NET Framework/Windows ships such an assembly, then without a clear enough justification, you should not use any NuGet package of the same name. 3) Read more pages on API Browser to get familiar with its organization of info. It explains to you, but you simply ignore.

Comment: Right, I was moving too fast. To be clear, I did download the sample and it was working. I just needed to port a small portion of it into an exising azure API where I already had similar token-handing "ADAL" business in it.. so.. I really wasn't expecting to run into a missing assembly .. my existing, working, API has so much overlap with the downloaded GitHub sample.. but apparently not complete overlap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case it looks like it's a system assembly (`System.IdentityModel.dll`).  However, if it were a NuGet package you can find which one in the following way:

1. Right click the class name (not namespace) and select `Go To Definition`
2. At the top of the file that is displayed is a `#region`, expand that region
3. Within the region is a comment containing the path the dll, within that path is the name of the NuGet package.

EDIT:
It looks like this would work even in your case, the comment when I do this for `BootstrapContext` goes here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IdentityModel.dll
```

This directory indicates that it's available from `Add Reference` --> `Assemblies`

Comment: thanks for not closing my question; and thanks for the clear level headed explanation; as experienced as I am, this bit of knowledge that seems basic to everyone else had escaped me all this time. I find that some of the NuGet packages out there that augment `System` namespaces are going to throw shade on whatever used to be patently obvious..